# NO BOOTABLE DEVICE message after ubuntu 14.04 installation in an acer V3-572G computer

Tags: 14.04, boot, acer

I have bought a brand new acer V3-572G computer which came with an windows installation. I erased the disk completely and installed ubuntu 14.04. I reboot and the screen displays the message NO BOOTABLE DEVICE. I have seen similar messages across this forum indicating that changing secure mode off in the BIOS and reinstalling should workd but it hasn't. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed ubuntu in UEFI mode or in legacy BIOS mode ? Try switching between the two modes and reboot your computer.

Configure the BIOS to boot from internal HDD.

Comment: i installed on UEFI and I am right now installing on legacy. I will tell you if it works...

Comment: IT WORKED!!!. I just changed to legacy, reinstalled everything and it worked